# Where can I find a simple and easy to read x86 backend?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, code-generation, register-allocation

Currently I'm working in a simple code generator to output an assembly-like language.

**Background:**

I've already working part of a register allocator but now I need to deal with instructions like `mul`/`div` which has fixed registers as input: `eax`/`ebx` which I don't know how to deal with it, so I'm looking for see how other implemenations does it. I've tried tcc. While the code is very small I find a bit hard to understand.

NOTE: I'm targeting C/C++ because it's the languages I'm more familiar with, but implementation in any language is very welcome.

Comment: clang ;) But on a more serious note you could take a look at [LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/).

Comment: The big open-source ones (GCC and Clang/LLVM) are not going to be much easier to understand, but I still recommend you at least take look at them. Other than that all you most likely find will be academic research projects, student assignments, and homegrown applications made for curiosities sake. For the last three, I guess the "readability" and ease of understanding will be in the order listed, with homegrown projects most likely the worst.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library, or favorite off-site resource are off topic here. See the [help/on-topic], item #5 in the numbered list.